# Emmet in StackSnippets™

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I think it would be a very nice addition to the StackSnippets™ to have **[Emmet](http://emmet.io/)** implemented in the editor.

**This is NOT an HTML/CSS replacement, it's a productivity tool meant to help you write faster**

For those of you who are unfamiliar, Emmet can turn CSS selectoresque strings such as `section#main>header>ul>li*5>{Item $}` to full fledged HTML markup like

```
<section id="main">
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</section>
```

It also works for CSS, things like `p0` to `padding: 0;`, `mt5p` to `margin-top: 5%;` and `t5` to `top: 5px;`

You type the line, press TAB and presto, insta-HTML in the editor. (In case you were thinking, the idea is to improve your typing time. <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> is faster to type than `padding: 0;`

For practical examples, try it out in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfojdkwp/)**

### Pros

- ***AWESOME!!***
- Very helpful in creating quick and dirty markup boilerplate.
- Relatively easy to implement (existing editor has an [official plugin](https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror)).
- No effect on existing workflow for users who don't know Emmet.

### Cons

- Slightly larger JS file.

Comment: This looks like it only benefits HTML editing.  Is everyone going to be asking for Emmet-like plugins in [their favorite language]?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Given that the editor is largely HTML, and there aren't any other generation plugins like that for JavaScript or CSS (not counting SASS/LESS, which I also would like to see implemented but is not as trivial as this). Also, only gains, no losses, so I don't really see why not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey also, forgot to mention. Emmet works for CSS too with things like `mt5` transforming to `margin-top: 5px`.

Comment: Not that I think a "they do it too!" argument is always valid, but hey, jsfiddle and jsbin do it too. It makes creating snippets a lot easier imo.

Comment: is stack snippets trademarked? either way, it's two words, not one

Comment: @Stephan: do they? How is this implemented in JS Fiddle? I just completely failed to find documentation on how to *use* it... :(

Comment: @DavidThomas, I went on searching, the stuff is pretty cool: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/26/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/ Just press tab after the command

Comment: I never understood the interest in html abstractions. @RobertHarvey there's [HAML](http://haml.info/) too. :/

Comment: Can we have a code tidy option (like jsfiddle) first? Pleeeasee. There is so much dirty markup in questions

Comment: @RobertHarvey even if everybody *Was* asking for Emmet for their own language I see no problem with that. It's only going to be implemented for important languages if at all.

Comment: I clicked on this in the sidebar because I thought that former SE dev [Emmett](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2749/emmett) was somehow trapped in the Stack Snippets.

Comment: Wouldn't this work better as a browser plugin? I can't see it actually adding benefit to how Stack Snippets work.

Comment: Yes I think this would be great but as a Stack App.

Comment: How have I never heard of Emmett before?!

Comment: AFAICS the vast majority of front-enders make extensive use of Emmet. IMHO, Emmet is far more important than syntax highlighting. And yet, judging by the amount of downvotes in this feature request, it looks like some people just don't want Stack Snippets to be usable at all. "Implement Emmet as a plugin?" Well, sure, why not just go one step further: trash the whole built-in Stack Snippet editor and implement a decent editor as a plugin then.

Comment: @canon Emmet is by no means an "abstraction". It just provides abbreviations which expand to perfectly valid HTML/CSS. That is, you waste less time typing and get the same valid HTML/CSS output.

Comment: Strongly agree to have this implemented, Emmet for HTML is somewhat equal to Markdown for Rich text. Less writing, while keeping readability. Though I would like to see it interpreted on showing, rather than expanded while writing.

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky Interpreted on showing ? You mean that it should stay as section#main>header>ul>li*5>{Item $} in sources ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet yes, just like markdown currently

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: _"Emmet is far more important than syntax highlighting"_ Yea... Nope. Hell no. Syntax highlighting helps explain obvious bugs in code to newer users, it makes code more readable, and works for the majority of programming languages out there. "Emmet" is just tool for lazy developers. If you're going to be writing HTML for a answer / question, you might as well do that in your fav IDE, then copy it over.

Comment: Up until now, no one has raised a single good argument against, and yet this post has 16 downvotes. If you disagree with it, please consider explaining what bothers you so much about it, either in a comment or in an answer.

Comment: In my experience, answers that require HTML are often more complex than basic lists / repeating elements. And I don't really see the added value of being able to write `div.container>span` opposed to `<div class="container><span></span></div>"`. @SecondRikudo: argument against: How would the syntax highlighter / markdown know your "Emmet markdown" is emmet, and not JS? You would have to include some sort of identifier specifying "This line should be interpreted as Emmet".

Comment: @Cerbrus You expand it yourself with TAB. It's not the job of the editor to parse it itself.

Comment: Ah, so @ClémentMalet's suggestion isn't valid any way.

I really don't see the added value. Sure, when developing repetitive HTML it's great (I use it too), but on SO? Nah.

Comment: But then again, you mentioned the existing editor has an official plugin? If it's trivial to implement, why not.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's a productivity tool, you don't have to use it if you don't like it. I know I'm using it on almost every jsFiddle example I create from scratch. Also, it's trivial to implement and has no implications on users who don't want it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree that syntax highlighting is more important to new users. If you re-read my comment which you've replied to, I've added an "IMHO" which implies that Emmet is more important than syntax highlighting in **my** workflow (sorry if the "my opinion" -> "my workflow" implication was not clear).

Comment: @Cerbrus By the way, I find Emmet extremely useful when writing CSS -- you should try it. `;)`

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess you have never tried Emmet, otherwise you would see the added value for both CSS and HTML. It's a shame that SO snippets still lacks this support. However, not surprisingly.

Comment: This post is over a year old... Seriously?